# JFIleChooser - Listen the changes while the FileChooser is open

Tags: java, swing, listener, jfilechooser

I know it can be a ridiculous question, but I'm trying very hard to listen the changes in the JFileChooser while is open.

I do NOT want to listen when the user clicks the APPROVE_OPTION or CANCEL_OPTION. My objective here is to count the files while the user selects, because if it reaches a limit (e.g., 20 selected files), I wanted to show an error message or something like it.

I've tried a lot of things like get the KeyStrokes, Binds, All the Listeners accessible by the JfileChosser object,... But nothing works.

If someone could help me... ;)

Thanks, anyway!

Comment: `PropertyChangeListener`?

Comment: Are you kidding me Bro? hahahaha
It worked, I've tried this for like 3 hours. You're really a MadProgrammer!!!
Thanks man!

Comment: Woowho! What a guess! Maybe, if you have something working, post an example of what you did as answer, it might be helpful to others (don't forget you can self answer/accept questions ;))

Comment: Clearly time to change name to MadBrogrammer. You could also look at the accessory component to display a running status of the validity of the selection/count-to-limit, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.

But with the help of the guys on the comment, I could do it.
I unset the buttons when it has more than the threshold, so the user it's not able to select.

Here it goes:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }
    public Example() {
        Container c = getContentPane();

        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);
        fileChooser.setDialogTitle("Max 20 files");
        fileChooser.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(fileChooser.getSelectedFiles().length>20){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "20 Files Max.\n", getWarningString(), JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE, null);
                    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(false);
                }
                else{
                    fileChooser.setControlButtonsAreShown(true);
                }
            }
        });
        int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);

    }
}
```